# Use custom tags in database content

Tags: django, django-templates

I am creating a custom CMS, with the purpose to learn more about Django.

What I'm trying to achieve is the use of tags in database content. I have a dynamic amount of placeholders attached to a page. Each placeholder can contain tags, like "current_time".

In the template I'm going to output the placeholder like this:

```
{% placeholder sidebar %}
```

And in the admin I want to do this:

```
This is the sidebar, the time is {% current_time "%Y-%m-%d %I:%M %p" %}
```

Well, the outputting is working, but the "current_time" tag isn't parsed. It's displayed as plain text. I have been looking for hours for a solution; tried regular tags, inclusion tags, simple tags, numerous snippets. But as you might guess, I still haven't found a solution.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Process the text as a template.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#using-the-template-system)

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. I forgot to mention that I have tried this method, but I'm getting this TemplateSyntaxError:

    Invalid block tag: 'current_time'

Even though "current_time" is loaded _before_ "placeholder".

Comment: Except they're loaded *outside*. You need to load `current_time` *inside*.

Comment: Wow. Didn't expect it would be so easy! Thanks alot!